# Beam/Dataflow ReadAllFromParquet doesn't read anything but my job still succeeds?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-iam

I have a Dataflow job which:

1. Reads a text file from GCS with other filenames in it
2. Passes the filenames to ReadAllFromParquet to read the .parquet files
3. Writes to BigQuery

Despite my job 'succeeding' it basically doesn't have an output collection past the ReadAllFromParquet step.
I successfully read the files in a list such as:`['gs://my_bucket/my_file1.snappy.parquet','gs://my_bucket/my_file2.snappy.parquet','gs://my_bucket/my_file3.snappy.parquet']`
I am also confirming this list is correct and the GCS paths to the files are correct using a logger on the step before ReadAllFromParquet.

That's what my pipeline looks like (omitting the full code for brevity but I am confident that it normally works as I have the exact same pipeline for .csv using ReadAllFromText and it works fine):

```
 with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options_batch) as pipeline_2:

    try:

        final_data = (
        pipeline_2
        |'Create empty PCollection' >> beam.Create([None])
        |'Get accepted batch file: {}'.format(runtime_options.complete_batch) >> beam.ParDo(OutputValueProviderFn(runtime_options.complete_batch))
        |'Read all filenames into a list'>> beam.ParDo(FileIterator(runtime_options.files_bucket))
        |'Read all files' >> beam.io.ReadAllFromParquet(columns=['locationItemId','deviceId','timestamp'])
        |'Process all files' >> beam.ParDo(ProcessSch2())
        |'Transform to rows' >> beam.ParDo(BlisDictSch2())
        |'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table = runtime_options.comp_table, 
                schema = SCHEMA_2,
                project = pipeline_options_batch.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).project, #options.display_data()['project'],
                create_disposition = beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,  #'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',#create if does not exist.
                write_disposition = beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND    #'WRITE_APPEND' #add to existing rows,partitoning
                )
        )
    except Exception as exception:
        logging.error(exception)
        pass
```

That's what my job diagram looks like after:

[image]

Does somebody have an idea what might be going wrong here and what's the best way to debug?
My ideas currently:

1. A bucket permissions issue. I noticed the bucket I am reading from is odd as earlier I couldn't download the files despite being a project Owner. The Owners of project only had 'Storage Legacy Bucket Owner'. I added 'Storage Admin' and it then worked fine when manually downloading files with my own account. As per the Dataflow documentation I have ensured that both the default compute service account as well as the dataflow one have 'Storage Admin' on this bucket. However, maybe that's all a red herring as ultimately if there was a permissions issue I should see this in the log and the job would fail?
2. ReadAllFromParquet expects the file patterns in a different format? I have showed an example of the list (in my diagram above I can see the input collection correctly shows elements added = 48 for 48 files in the list) I supply above. I know this format works for ReadAllFromText so I assumed that they are equivalent and should work.

=========

EDIT:
Noticed something else potentially consequential. Comparing against my other job which uses ReadAllFromText and works fine I noticed a slight mismatch in the naming that is worrying.

This is the name of the output collection for my working job:
[image]

And that's the name on my parquet job that doesn't actually read anything:
[image]

Note specifically

```
Read all files/ReadAllFiles/ReadRange.out0
```

vs

```
Read all files/Read all files/ReadRange.out0
```

The first part of the path is the name of my step for both jobs.
But I believe the second to be the ReadAllFiles class from apache_beam.io.filebasedsource (https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py) which both ReadAllFromText and ReadAllFromParquet call.

Seems like a potential bug but don't seem to be able to trace it in the source code.

=============
**EDIT 2**

After some more digging it seems that ReadAllFromParquet just isn't functional yet. ReadFromParquet calls apache_beam.io.parquetio._ParquetSource whereas ReadAllFromParquet simply calls
apache_beam.io.filebasedsource._ReadRange.

I wonder if there's a way to turn this on if it's an experimental function?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned if you are using the last Beam SDK, try using SDK 2.16 to test the last changes.

The doc states that [ReadAllFromParquet](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/apache_beam.io.parquetio.html#apache_beam.io.parquetio.ReadAllFromParquet) is an experimental funtion as well as ReadFromParquet; nonetheless, [ReadFromParquet](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/apache_beam.io.parquetio.html#apache_beam.io.parquetio.ReadFromParquet) is reported as working in this thread [Apache-Beam: Read parquet files from nested HDFS directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56834077/apache-beam-read-parquet-files-from-nested-hdfs-directories), you might want to try to using this funtion.

Comment: ReadFromParquet does work. ReadAllFromParquet currently just points to the same classes as ReadAllFromText with no capability to read parquet. You can confirm this by checking the source code in the link you shared. That is unless 2.16 has changes that are not visible in the source code?

Comment: The [master branch](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/parquetio.py) is supposed to contain the last modifications, but you can check other versions as well. From my review the classes ReadAllFromParquet and ReadFromParquet both of them call _ParquetSource, I was wondering how you reached apache_beam.io.filebasedsource._ReadRange in the note 'EDIT 2' in your original question. In any case, since ReadFromParquet is working, I would recommend continue using that function.

Comment: thanks for the input. I was actually looking at the pydoc hosted on apache.org here https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/parquetio.html#ReadAllFromParquet but now realised that's 2.11!

I have luckily had a change in my job's objectives so we don't need those parquet files anymore so simply dropped this for now.

When I can I will definitely come back as if 2.15 which is what I use does call _ParquetSource the issue is somewhere else in my code.

Comment: Sure, I'll try to help if you come back with new results.